# Test case fails while running from command line

Tags: command-line, selendroid

I am new at selendroid and trying to run my tests using the command line.

When I run my test from eclipse, it runs fine. But when I run them from the command line, they fail.

I have already started the selendroid server.

Please help me? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post your script to allow us understand the problem.

Comment: Please add the command line command you are using / trying to execute.